# Magento Store View Switcher

Tags: magento, view, store

I have a couple of days to get as much done with a localization project as I can before I am off to a new position with a new employer.

We are working on having multiple store views based on locale/currency/(to a lesser extent)language.

We want users to be GeoIP redirected to the proper store view - IE - Australian-English-AUD, US-English-USD, UK-English-GBP, etc. For now, only English is supported, but ultimately this needs to support other languages.

We are working with the custom Acumen 1.2.8 theme from Themeforest, and it is highly customized. This is also Magento 1.6. Acumen 1.2.9 is the proper version to go with Magento 1.6, but the fellows who set these up didn't realize this, and upgrading now is probably going to be a bad idea.

I have managed to display different switchers in the site's header, but none of them work properly. The language switcher displays the proper store views, but is not redirecting properly (currency still shows as US, at least to me, maybe AU users will see AU currency).

All I need is the switcher to display and for it to redirect to the proper store view, taking precedence over any GeoIP redirects.

Any thoughts on this are greatly appreciated, as I'm a bit stuck and would prefer to get this at a point in the next two days where I can hand it off to someone else that can then complete it.

Comment: My problem here was that in admin config, I had multiple allowed currencies chosen for each store view. I changed each view to only have the current currency as allowable and it started working normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pspahn wrote:

> My problem here was that in admin config, I had multiple allowed
>   currencies chosen for each store view. I changed each view to only
>   have the current currency as allowable and it started working
>   normally.